# VideoView with Gesture(Swipe function) in android

Tags: android, gesture, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to combine default **VideoView** and **gesture listener**,

I want to implement likewise on VideoView if user swipe left then song plays backward or swipe right then song plays forward.

open default media player via following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
    startActivity(intent);
```

then how to add gesture listener ..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got that how to combine VideoView and GestureListener :

layout file **activity_main.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** file :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {

VideoView videoView;
MainActivity activity;
MediaController mediaController;
AudioManager audioManager;
GestureDetection detector;
int currentPosition;
int currentVolume;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    detector = new GestureDetection(this, this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
    this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String filePath = null;

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        switch (resultCode) {

        case RESULT_OK:
            Uri selectedAudio = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedAudio,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            break;
        default:
            finish();
        }
        if (filePath != null) {
            mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        } else
            finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "";

    switch (direction) {

    case GestureDetection.SWIPE_LEFT:

        currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition() - 10000;
        videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
        str = "Swipe Left";
        break;

    case GestureDetection.SWIPE_RIGHT:

        currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition() + 10000;
        videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
        str = "Swipe Right";
        break;

    case GestureDetection.SWIPE_DOWN:

        currentVolume = audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                currentVolume - 1, 0);
        str = "Swipe Down";
        break;
    case GestureDetection.SWIPE_UP:

        currentVolume = audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                currentVolume + 1, 0);
        str = "Swipe Up";
        break;

    }
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

**GestureDetection.java** class :

```
public class GestureDetection extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

public final static int SWIPE_UP = 1;
public final static int SWIPE_DOWN = 2;
public final static int SWIPE_LEFT = 3;
public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

public final static int MODE_SOLID = 1;
public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC = 2;

private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; // just an unlikely number
private int swipe_Min_Distance = 50;
private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
private boolean running = true;
private boolean tapIndicator = false;

private Activity context;

private GestureDetector detector;
private SimpleGestureListener listener;

public GestureDetection(Activity context, SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

    this.context = context;
    this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    this.listener = sgl;
}

public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!this.running)
        return;

    boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

        if (event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        else if (result)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if (this.tapIndicator) {
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            this.tapIndicator = false;
        }

    }
    // else just do nothing, it's Transparent
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {

    final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
    final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

    if (xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance
            || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
        return false;

    velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
    velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
    boolean result = false;

    if (velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
            && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
        if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);
        else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);

        result = true;
    } else if (velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
            && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
        if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
        else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

    if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {
        arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);

        this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
    }

    return false;
}

static interface SimpleGestureListener {
    void onSwipe(int direction);

}

}
```