# Android: Video View + Gesture

Tags: android, video, gesture

I want to combine :

1. default VideoView with media controller and
2. gesture listener.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904826/videoview-with-gestureswipe-function-in-android/23102543#23102543) but for me (Moto E - 1st gen) "Cant play this video" appears for all the videos I tried.

Please help me with a supporting video file or any other working example.

Comment: Now its working after some research done over that.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your player settings. whether it supports all types of mp4 formats some thing like MPEG and other. If it does not work then check your video resolution.